# Restart countdown automatically every day

Tags: javascript, counter

I am using the following code to:

1. Show the remaining time for an "X" event.
2. Print text when that event is> 0.
3. Calculate 2 hours of event duration and print something else.

I love how this works, but I want that when the event ends, the counter automatically prints the remaining time for the same event the next day.

```js
    // Set the date we're counting down to
    // Year, Month ( 0 for January ), Day, Hour, Minute, Second, , Milliseconds
    //:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    //::::::::::::                                       ::::::::::::
    //::::::::::::              4:00 PM                  ::::::::::::
    //::::::::::::                                       ::::::::::::
    //:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    //                                   (AAAA, MM, DD, HH, mm, S ));
    var countDownDate = new Date(Date.UTC(2021, 07, 16, 23, 00, 00));

function chiriTimer() {
// Update the count down every 1 second
    var x = setInterval(function () {

        // Get todays date and time
        var now = new Date().getTime();

        // Find the distance between now an the count down date
        // GMT/UTC Adjustment at the end of the function. 0 = GMT/UTC+0; 1 = GMT/UTC+1.
        var distance = countDownDate - now - (3600000 * 1);

        // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
        var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

        // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
        for (const ele of document.getElementsByClassName("chiriTimer")){
            ele.innerHTML = (days + "<span>d</span> " + hours + "<span>h</span> "
                + minutes + "<span>m</span> " + seconds + "<span>s</span><br />")
        }
        
        // If the count down is over, write some text
    if (distance < 0) {
      for (const ele of document.getElementsByClassName("chiriTimer")) {
        ele.innerHTML = "<p class='live-text'>En Vivo <i class='fa fa-circle faa-flash animated'></i></p> ";
      }
      if (distance + 7200000 < 0) {
        for (const allEllements of document.getElementsByClassName("chiriTimer")) {
          allEllements.innerHTML = "Finalizó";
        }
      }
    }
  }, 1000);
}

chiriTimer()
```

```html
<p class="chiriTimer"></p>
```

Comment: Could you explain "the remaining time for the same event the next day"?

Comment: I mean, my "chiriTimer" function prints me a "countdown" at a specific date and time: 2021, 07, 16, 23, 00, 00. But I need that when more than three hours pass, then now my date is: 2021 , 07, 17, 23, 00, 00. Changing the day, but keeping the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To repeat the countdown for the next day three hours after the current countdown is over.  Before the code that checking for two hours due, check for three hours due first `distance + 10800000 < 0`, then change the `countDownDate` to the next date.

```
function chiriTimer() {
// Update the count down every 1 second
    var x = setInterval(function () {

        // Get todays date and time
        var now = new Date().getTime();

        // Find the distance between now an the count down date
        // GMT/UTC Adjustment at the end of the function. 0 = GMT/UTC+0; 1 = GMT/UTC+1.
        var distance = countDownDate - now - (3600000 * 1);

        // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
        var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

        // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
        for (const ele of document.getElementsByClassName("chiriTimer")){
            ele.innerHTML = (days + "<span>d</span> " + hours + "<span>h</span> "
                + minutes + "<span>m</span> " + seconds + "<span>s</span><br />")
        }
        
        // If the count down is over, write some text
    if (distance < 0) {
      for (const ele of document.getElementsByClassName("chiriTimer")) {
        ele.innerHTML = "<p class='live-text'>En Vivo <i class='fa fa-circle faa-flash animated'></i></p> ";
      }
      if (distance + 10800000 < 0) {
        countDownDate = new Date(countDownDate.getTime() + 86400000)
      } else if (distance + 7200000 < 0) {
        for (const allEllements of document.getElementsByClassName("chiriTimer")) {
          allEllements.innerHTML = "Finalizó";
        }
      }
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: It works perfect. Thanks a lot.
I was trying to do it with an if condition that calculated if days and minutes less than zero, but it didn't work for me.